# bash script calling ls worked perfectly until I renamed the directory the script runs in

Tags: bash, shell, ls

I wrote a bash script in /home/maxg/SpProData. It ran just fine.
The target machine's directory for the script is called /home/maxg/sppro

In order to test the script on the machine it was written on, I renamed it from /home/maxg/SpProData to /home/maxg/sppro.

I changed the home directory variable for the script, and it gets now stuck at where an ls command result is passed into a variable, like so:

```
_WORKING_ZIP=$(ls -td ${_SP_LINK_CFG_FILENAME}_${_PERF_DIR_NAME_PREFIX}Archive_${_TODAY_VARIANT}_* | head -1)
```

resulting in:

```
[info ] Looking for the PerformanceDataArchive (.zip) file ...
find ............. ArgyleCourt_PerformanceDataArchive_2020-05-09_*
ls: cannot access 'ArgyleCourt_PerformanceDataArchive_2020-05-09_*': No such file or directory
[error] (2) = ls had a more serious problem; e.g. directory or file not found... exiting!
```

The constants are:

```
SP-LINK cfg file name...: ArgyleCourt
Perf DIR name prefix....: PerformanceData
Today variant...........: 2020-05-09
SP PRO directory........: /home/maxg/sppro
```

The file exist:

```
drwxrwxr-x  3 maxg maxg  4096 May 16 19:59 .
drwxr-xr-x 56 maxg maxg  4096 May 16 19:33 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 maxg maxg 55477 May  9 02:03 ArgyleCourt_PerformanceDataArchive_2020-05-09_02-03-07.zip
-rw-rw-r--  1 maxg maxg 56208 May 15 22:27 GetSpProData.awk
-rw-rw-r--  1 maxg maxg  1511 May 16 19:52 GetSpProData.conf
-rwxrwxr-x  1 maxg maxg 23530 May 16 20:04 GetSpProData.sh
```

Running the command in the terminal returns the desired result:

```
ls ArgyleCourt_PerformanceDataArchive_2020-05-09_*
ArgyleCourt_PerformanceDataArchive_2020-05-09_02-03-07.zip
```

This makes no sense at all. Only two changes were made:

1. rename the directory
2. change the home directory constant to point to the new name.

... later on:

I changed the directory name (and variable) back to SpProData, same non-working result.

... later on:

Copied the scrip to the target machine and it runs!
(Looks like a long night) :(

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving a relative path instead of an absolute path.

Try

```
_WORKING_ZIP=$(ls -td /home/maxg/sppro/${_SP_LINK_CFG_FILENAME}_${_PERF_DIR_NAME_PREFIX}Archive_${_TODAY_VARIANT}_* | head -1)
```

Edit: Also don't `parse ls`

You can use

```
_WORKING_ZIP=$(head -1 <<< /home/maxg/sppro/${_SP_LINK_CFG_FILENAME}_${_PERF_DIR_NAME_PREFIX}Archive_${_TODAY_VARIANT}_*)
```

Example :

```
$ls my_file_is_here.txt
ls: cannot access 'my_file_is_here.txt': No such file or directory
$ls ~/test/my_file_is_here.txt
/home/renegade/test/my_file_is_here.txt
$cd ~/test/
$ls my_file_is_here.txt
my_file_is_here.txt
$
```

Comment: The script is 600 lines, too long to post... but an absolute path would have prevented the problem at 'that' location. The script converts a bunch of files, hence, lots of paths and the cd was the lazy approach to work with relative paths. BTW: why not parse ls?

Comment: @MaxG Read this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead

Comment: Oh these little quirks! :) :(

Answer (score 0):

Well... thank you for reading, and sorry for your time.

Only two changes?! NO... three changes...

I moved a statement further up, yes as early as possible...

```
cd $_SP_PRO_DIR
```

... too early! Before the config file was read, which defines this constant.

This resulted in a cd statement without an argument.
And a cd without an argument goes up to the parent level.

Hence the ls command could not find the file.

Well, another hard lesson learned. :)